# Multiple ifs within list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I've used a list comprehension which is supposed to store `keys` and `values` in `itemDict` variable considering the fact that some items if present in `item['keys']` will not be included in `itemDict`. I've used multiple if conditions to make that possible.

This is what I've tried with:

```
itemDict = {item['keys']:item['value'] for item in soup.select('input[keys]') if '$cmdPrint' not in item['name'] and 'btnView' not in item['name'] and 'btnMyDoc' not in item['key']}
```

***How can I rewrite those conditions to make it concise?***

Comment: I suggest using a `for` loop.

Comment: Not using a list comprehension is probably the best idea. But you could also extract the if conditions into a single function call

Comment: Being concise is a fickle goal. Better to be readable, span a few extra lines and value your time and that of those who have to read your code after you.

Comment: Great example of an incomprehensible (and undebuggable) list comprehension. Well done. Suggest you use for loops -much more maintainable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `check` function and use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) builtin. Also reformat the comprehension for readability.

```
def check(item):
    return all(('$cmdPrint' not in item['name'],
           'btnView' not in item['name'],
           'btnMyDoc' not in item['key']))

itemDict = {item['keys']:item['value']
            for item in soup.select('input[keys]')
            if check(item)}
```

Or use it in the comprehension, but that's one long comprehension.

```
itemDict = {item['keys']:item['value']
            for item in soup.select('input[keys]')
            if all(('$cmdPrint' not in item['name'],
                    'btnView' not in item['name'],
                    'btnMyDoc' not in item['key']))}
```

Or just use a regular for loop:

```
itemDict = {}
for item in soup.select('input[keys]')
    if check(item):
        itemDict[item['keys']] = item['value']
```